# Aliases for .net objects/methods, etc

Tags: vb.net

One of our customers has requested changes to the names of dozens of the objects in our very large object hierarchy. This will definitely help them, as it maps our objects onto their real-world business object names.

Of course I don't want to change working code, so I'd prefer to use some sort of "alias" object for each of these renaming. I suspect that I can do this by declaring a second object with the alias'ed name, and then overriding any of the alias'ed methods…

But what happens when the object name doesn't change, only a method within it? This could get messy!

Anyone out there faced a similar problem or have any advice on how to attack this?

Comment: Have you considered implementing it as a new assembly (with it's own namespace) which wraps the original one, or as a second namespace within the same assembly?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding this… how would a different assembly or namespace achieve this? Gah, return=post, editing… I would still have to make a new object with the new name and inherit from the original, right? The namespace would simply isolate those objects in their own package?

Comment: Correct, you would still need to create a new derived class for each of the original classes, but it would keep them organized and, by having them in a separate namespace, you could have them reuse the same class names, when necessary, without having the names conflict with the original ones.

Comment: How is your client consuming your objects?

Comment: Inheritance would probably only work if your objects have native type properties (strings, integers etc). You would be in a world of maintenance pain if you had to walk the entire property tree just in order to return the correct aliased types for all the properties of every object.

Comment: Why do they absolutely have to have another name? Why can't they make the mapping themselves? How about your other customers? Would they like it if you "change" the names? I am rather curious what the exact reason is for your customer to ask you to change your library / code.

Comment: Gavin, they're using it as a COM library in Excel. There

Comment: Gavin, they're using it as a COM library in Excel. There's no *type* aliasing going on, just the method calls IIRC and all the object names are wrapped in getter/setters. (sorry, took too long editing)